# richtextbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

i am using a richtext box in my vb.net application and i need to dispaly top ten records from the database in it.but it is displaying only 1 record.what to do??
kindly help.....

Comment: We're going to need a good bit more than, "Help, it's broken." Please provide a code sample.

Comment: Whats the command you are using to update textbox with value from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following lines of code and it works absolutely fine:

```
 If rcount < 10 Then
     rcount = rcount + 1
     RtxtMessage.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None
     RtxtMessage.Text = RtxtMessage.Text + " " + 
     CType(dv.Item(i)("audit_message"), String) & vbCrLf
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have chosen the wrong control. You may want to look into using a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx), or some other control that exists to display multiple records.

If you really want to display the values of 10 records in a TextBox, you'll have to approach the problem differently. You can concatenate the values into a string and assign it to the Text property of the TextBox, although I don't think this is really a good solution.